# Zuul RibbonRoutingFilter Content-Encoding gzip response

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

In our setup, We are accessing the Node JS server thorough ZUUL and Sidecar.

When we invoke the java scripts resources with *Accept-Encoding=[gzip]* header, Node JS returns compressed file with *Content-Encoding=[gzip]* header. But if the same request is routed through Zuul we are getting a decompressed response.

Based on our analysis we found that

When the request is forwarded to downstream systems based on service id, zuul is using the ribbon load balanced routing filter. In this process, the apache HTTP client removes the below headers from response in *ResponseContentEncoding* class
o   "Content-Length"
o   "Content-Encoding"
o   "Content-MD5"
Because of that the content is automatically decompressed in zuul and send it to the caller.

When the request is forwarded to downstream systems based on URL, zuul is using simple host routing filter. In this flow, *disableContentCompression* method is used while building the HTTP client so the content is sent to the caller without decompressing.

Please let me know of any specific reason for not using *disableContentCompression* in *ribbonloadbalancedroutingfilter* route and let me know of any workaround to resolve this?

Environment :
Spring Cloud version: Dalston.SR2 
Spring Boot: 1.5.4.RELEASE

Comment: Maybe you can report this as an issue on Spring Cloud Netflix Github - [https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues).